# How can I create Expanded panel

Tags: dart, flutter

[Here](https://material.io/guidelines/components/expansion-panels.html#expansion-panels-behavior) is a material design of `Expanded panel` that looks like:

[image]

I'd like to make a similar one with `Flutter`, not sure if I've to start with something like the below code or know, and how to complete it!

```
new ExpansionPanelList(
  children: <ExpansionPanel>[
    new ExpansionPanel(
      headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
            isExpanded = true;
            return new ListTile(
            // leading: item.iconpic,
            title: new Text(
            "First",
            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
            style: new TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            ),
            ));
          },
      body: new Text("school"),
      isExpanded: true,
    ),
    new ExpansionPanel(
      headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
        isExpanded = true;
        return new ListTile(
          // leading: item.iconpic,
            title: new Text(
              "Second",
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              style: new TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              ),
            ));
      },
      isExpanded: false,
      body: new Text("hospital"),
    ),
    new ExpansionPanel(
        headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
          isExpanded = true;
          return new ListTile(
            // leading: item.iconpic,
              title: new Text(
                "Third",
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                style: new TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                ),
              ));
        },
        body: new Text("va facility"),
        isExpanded: true)
    ]),
```

**UPDATE**

I just need to start and have the empty panels

[image]

Comment: You're not very clear on *what* you're trying to do here. Do you want the entire thing replicated, top to bottom (including the Barbados tag etc)? Are you having trouble getting the expansion panels to build? Are you having trouble with the layout? It would be useful to post a picture of what you have and to tell us the difference between what you have and what you want to see.

Comment: @rmtmckenzie I've trouble getting the expansion panels to build, do not know how to start

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expansion Panel List in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45559580/expansion-panel-list-in-flutter)

Comment: @aziza I read that one, but did not understand it or know how to start, kindly see my update to the question.

Comment: @rmtmckenzie I updated my question to have it more clear.

Comment: The question linked above has a full working example, what is your question exactly ?

Comment: Do you want the exact same look in your image (the header part and the body part in separate cards) ?

Comment: not this ? https://i.imgur.com/kylAOPn.gif

Comment: @aziza exactly the last one, how can I make it!

Comment: @aziza I need 2 separate cards, header and body, empty, I can fill then later

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case if you particularly need to mimic the images you referenced from the material design. You would want to build your own custom expansion panel.

I have a simple example using [`AnimatedContainer`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/AnimatedContainer-class.html) to show you how to create the expanded and collapsed effects, and it is up to you to populate both the header and the body sections with what you want.

[image]

```
class AnimateExpanded extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AnimateExpandedState createState() => new _AnimateExpandedState();
}

class _AnimateExpandedState extends State<AnimateExpanded> {
  double _bodyHeight = 0.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[500],
      body: new SingleChildScrollView(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Card(
              child: new Container(
                height: 50.0,
                child: new Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new IconButton(
                      icon: new Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          this._bodyHeight = 300.0;
                        });
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            new Card(
              child: new AnimatedContainer(
                child: new Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new IconButton(
                      icon: new Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_up),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          this._bodyHeight = 0.0;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                height: _bodyHeight,
                // color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What image, you mean the gif in the answer ?

Comment: I use ScreenToGif

Comment: Hi I am a bit new to flutter. I just want to ask If I have multiple collapsable on same screen. How do I handle that. I am currently using your code @aziza , Its working fine for 1, But When I add multiple, It opens all the collapsables if I click on any one of them

Comment: This is great! How do you go about making the "opened" height dynamic, specifically equaling the total height of the AnimatedContainer's child (which in my case is a Column with multiple children)?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ExpansionTile` inside `ListView` like this

```
        ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: <Widget>[
                ExpansionTile(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
                  leading: Icon(Icons.event),
                  title: Text('Test1'),
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ListTile(title: Text('Title of the item')),
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text('Title of the item2'),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                ExpansionTile(
                  title: Text('Test2'),
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ListTile(title: Text('Title of the item')),
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text('Title of the item2'),
                    )
                  ],
                )
              ],
            )
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working example (including main etc so you can just paste into a file and run)

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ListItem {
  final WidgetBuilder bodyBuilder;
  final String title;
  final String subtitle;
  bool isExpandedInitially;

  ListItem({
    @required this.bodyBuilder,
    @required this.title,
    this.subtitle = "",
    this.isExpandedInitially = false,
  })  : assert(title != null),
        assert(bodyBuilder != null);

  ExpansionPanelHeaderBuilder get headerBuilder =>
      (context, isExpanded) => new Row(children: [
            new SizedBox(width: 100.0, child: new Text(title)),
            new Text(subtitle)
          ]);
}

class ExpansionList extends StatefulWidget {
  /// The items that the expansion list should display; this can change
  /// over the course of the object but probably shouldn't as it won't
  /// transition nicely or anything like that.
  final List<ListItem> items;

  ExpansionList(this.items) {
    // quick check to make sure there's no duplicate titles.
    assert(new Set.from(items.map((li) => li.title)).length == items.length);
  }

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new ExpansionListState();
}

class ExpansionListState extends State<ExpansionList> {
  Map<String, bool> expandedByTitle = new Map();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new ExpansionPanelList(
      children: widget.items
          .map(
            (item) => new ExpansionPanel(
                headerBuilder: item.headerBuilder,
                body: new Builder(builder: item.bodyBuilder),
                isExpanded:
                    expandedByTitle[item.title] ?? item.isExpandedInitially),
          )
          .toList(growable: false),
      expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
        setState(() {
          expandedByTitle[widget.items[index].title] = !isExpanded;
        });
      },
    );
  }
}

void main() => runApp(
      new MaterialApp(
        home: new SingleChildScrollView(
          child: new SafeArea(
            child: new Material(
              child: new ExpansionList(
                [
                  new ListItem(
                      title: "Title 1",
                      subtitle: "Subtitle 1",
                      bodyBuilder: (context) => new Text("Body 1")),
                  new ListItem(
                      title: "Title 2",
                      subtitle: "Subtitle 2",
                      bodyBuilder: (context) => new Text("Body 1"),
                      isExpandedInitially: true)
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

If I had to guess, you're missing the parts where you pass in expanded into each expansion header, and the part where you keep track of whether each expansion header is expanded or not.

I've done it a particular way here that assumes each title is unique; you could do something similar but rely on different properties. Or you could build everything in the initState method of your ExpansionListState equivalent.

[This](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/expansion_panels_demo.dart) is a full working example of pretty much the exact UI you have in the picture in your post. You can simply download the [flutter gallery](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.flutter.gallery&hl=en_CA) from the play store to see the result. They did it a different way than I did (building everything in the initState method), and it's more complicated than what I did, but would be worth understanding as well.

Hope that helps =)