# ExpansionPanelList not expanding nor collapsing ExpansionPanel

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm using `ExpansionPanel()`s inside a `Tab()`. The `ExpansionPanel()` shows correctly. But its `isExpanded` attribute never changes (and yes, I have a line that should change it) making it impossible to collapse or expand the `ExpansionPanel()`

I tried to use the answers of [Expansion Panel List in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45559580/expansion-panel-list-in-flutter) and [Can't create ExpansionPanelList with Items in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45104182/cant-creat-expansionpanellist-with-items-in-flutter/45104992#45104992) but none of them worked.

I also tried to follow [Flutter ExpansionPanel Demo](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/expansion_panels_demo.dart) but didn't work.

```dart
// ...

class _PlaceExpandedPanelItem {
  _PlaceExpandedPanelItem({this.isExpanded, this.header, this.body, this.icon});

  bool isExpanded;
  final String header;
  final Widget body;
  final Icon icon;
}

class _HomePage extends State<HomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  TabController _tabController;

  List<_PlaceExpandedPanelItem> _placeExpandedPanelItems = <_PlaceExpandedPanelItem>[
    _PlaceExpandedPanelItem(
      isExpanded: true,
      header: 'Header',
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('Body')
        ],
      ),
      icon: null
    ),
    _PlaceExpandedPanelItem(
        isExpanded: false,
        header: 'Header',
        body: Text('Body'),
        icon: null
    ),
  ];

  List<Tab> _allTabs;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _allTabs = <Tab>[
      Tab(
          child: Container(
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                new ExpansionPanelList(
                  expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
                    setState(() {
                      _placeExpandedPanelItems[index].isExpanded = !_placeExpandedPanelItems[index].isExpanded;
                    });
                  },
                  children: _placeExpandedPanelItems.map((_PlaceExpandedPanelItem _placeExpandedPanelItem){
                    return ExpansionPanel(
                      headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
                        return Text(_placeExpandedPanelItem.isExpanded.toString());
                      },
                      isExpanded: _placeExpandedPanelItem.isExpanded,
                      body: _placeExpandedPanelItem.body,
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                )
              ],
            ),
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          )
      ),
      Tab(
        child: Text('Tab 2'),
      ),
      Tab(
        child: Text('Tab 3'),
      ),
    ];

    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: _allTabs.length);
  }

// ...
```

I expect the `ExpansionPanel()` to collapse or expand when the `expansionCallback` is called, but it doesn't collapse nor expand.

Comment: Your code works for me perfectly...

Comment: I took ```_allTab``` out of ```initState()``` and put it in ```build()``` before returning ```Scaffold```, and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Initializing widgets on `initState()` may cause for `Widget build` to be called first without waiting for initState() to finish. If the widgets aren't needed to be on initState(), it's better for them to be moved inside `Widget build()`.