# ExpansionPanelList Scroll Issue

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an ExpansionPanelList inside a ListView and I'm unable to get it to scroll when trying in the middle of the screen, though it will work on the edges. I've attached the code below. I'm guessing its the ExpansionPanelList that isn't letting me scroll but I'm not sure why because the items are inside a ListView as well.

I've taken a video of the issue https://drive.google.com/file/d/19zM7cfjshcN8OfEbRhvxIgmUp8sq1TP6/view?usp=sharing

```
  _bodyBuilder() {
    return
      ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        children: <Widget>[
      ExpansionPanelList.radio(
              initialOpenPanelValue: 2,
              children: dateList.map<ExpansionPanelRadio>((DateTime date) {
                return ExpansionPanelRadio(
                  canTapOnHeader: true,
                  value: date.day,
                  headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(date)),
                    );
                  },
                  body: Container(
                    //child: ListView.separated(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: cleanRecords
                          .where((Log) =>
                      DateTime.parse(DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd')
                          .format(Log.time.toDateTime()))
                          .toString() ==
                          date.toString())
                          .toList()
                          .length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        final records = cleanRecords
                            .where((Log) =>
                        DateTime.parse(DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd')
                            .format(Log.time.toDateTime()))
                            .toString() ==
                            date.toString())
                            .toList();
                        final schedule = records[index];
                        return ListTile(
                          title: Text(DateFormat('hh:mm').format(schedule.time.toDateTime())),
                          subtitle: Text(schedule.notes),
                          onTap: () => _updateRecord(schedule.parentID, schedule.id),
                        );
                      },
                      // separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                      //   return Divider();
                      // },
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }).toList(),
            )
    ],

      );// ListTiles++
  }
```

Comment: Is there any reason it's in a listview, since it 's the only widget? Assuming expansiontile is also scrollable. The reason for your problem is that both widgets have scrollphysics and that won't work

Comment: The reason I had it in a ListView was due to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45104182/cant-create-expansionpanellist-with-items-in-flutter/55927544 but it seemed like the clashing scroll physics were a good bet so I moved it to a Column instead, but now I have no scrolling at all and get a bottom overflow. Looks like if I want scrolling I'll need a different widget or to customise ExpansionPanelList

Comment: @Stijn2210 Thanks a lot, I've been thinking a lot about this and turns out that it is the reason! Rather than the ListView scrollphysics clashing with the ExpansionPanel scrollphysics, its the nested ListView scrollphysics clashing with the outer ListView scrollphysics. Setting primary: false on the inner ListView solved the problem